# How do I return a promise from my service to my controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have asked this is several variations but I now have some definitive code that contains a bug I can't dig out.

I have an Angular service like this:

```
.service("lookupDataService", [
        '$q', '$http', '$timeout',  function($q, $http, $timeout) {
    this.brokers = function() {
        var cachedBrokers = localStorage.getItem("brokers");

        if (!cachedBrokers) {
            return $http.get('/api/brokers')
                .success(function (data) {
                    localStorage.setItem("brokers", data);
                });
        } else {
            return $timeout(function () {
                return {
                    "data": localStorage.getItem("brokers")
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}])
```

and I consume this service in my controller

```
$scope.loadData = function() {
    $scope.promise = $q.all([
        lookupDataService.brokers()
        .then(function(data) { $scope.enquiriesBrokers = data; }),
    ]);
};
```

Now I know there are several problems with this code, but I am mainly focused on trying to return a promise to my controller from the service. For example, the $q apparently does nothing with its promise, but I assure you it does later in the code.

Inspecting the data in the service retrieves the desires results, but when this trickles to the controller, the data is [Object object] rather than an array of these.

How do I return a promise when I don't have one?

Here is a sample of the JSON returned from the service:

[image: JSON in Fiddler]

And here is a sample of the HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <label for="enquiries-broker">Broker:</label>
    <select ng-model="equiriesSelectedBroker" class="form-control" ng-options="broker.brokerCodeField for broker in enquiriesBrokers" id="enquiries-broker">
        <option value="">Please select a broker</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to do `$scope.enquiriesBrokers = data.data;` in your factory success method of controller

Comment: does that fixed your issue?

Comment: Nope! My dropdown is full of empty elements. I think its is grabbing the data but maybe local storage is messing it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the  **$q** object and return promise

```
.service("lookupDataService", [
    '$q', '$http', '$timeout',  function($q, $http, $timeout) {
this.brokers = function() {
   var defer = $q.defer()

    var cachedBrokers = localStorage.getItem("brokers");

    if (!cachedBrokers) {
          $http.get('/api/brokers')
            .success(function (data) {
                 // defer resolve
                 defer.resolve({data:data}) 
                localStorage.setItem("brokers", angular.toJson(data));
            });
    } else {
         // defer resolve
         defer.resolve({data:angular.fromJson(cachedBrokers) })
    }
   // defer return promise
   return defer.promise;
  }
 }])
```

So you will **always get promise** from service even if there is no $http call

**EDIT:**

Populating `SELECT` with JSON so the `ng-model` will obtain  **userIdField**

`broker.userIdField as broker.brokerCodeField for broker in enquiriesBrokers` is telling that use `broker.userIdField` as value and  `broker.brokerCodeField` as label

```
<select ng-model="equiriesSelectedBroker" class="form-control" 
ng-options="broker.userIdField as broker.brokerCodeField for broker in enquiriesBrokers" id="enquiries-broker">
    <option value="">Please select a broker</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That looks great, thank you. My code is now compiling and is using the cache. The only thing is the dropdown for which this promise is requested is not being populated. Any ideas? My controller consumption has not changed from the code snippet above.

Comment: Let me show your JSON from the server, and dropdown setup you have in HTML

Comment: I have added more detail above

Comment: thanks, i just updated my answer to reflect the solution do not forget to change in controller  `$scope.enquiriesBrokers = data.data`

Comment: we forgot to parse strings for localStorage and from localStorage with `angular.toJson(data)` resp  `angular.fromJson(data)`  see update above

Comment: Fabulous. With a little tinkering I got it working. Thank you thank you thank you!